# Dapper Mapping of Nested Objects within Nested Objects in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, orm, dapper

I am currently working with a set of data coming from a SQL DB, and would like to know the proper way to map it using Dapper, regarding a column within a JSON object.

Shape of the JSON object coming from the DB via a FOR JSON PATH select statement within the overal query:

```
widget: [
 {
  id: 'int',
  name: 'string',
  x: 'int',
  y: 'int'
 },{...}
]
```

I would like to map the X and Y values to a class within my .NET Application.
To produce an object that looks like this: (Where the X and Y values are nested in a Layout object)

```
widget: [
 {
  id: 'int',
  name: 'string',
  layout: {
    x: 'int',
    y: 'int'
  }
 },{...}
]
```

The C# classes appears as such: (omitting {get;set;} here)

```
public class Data {
  public int Id
  public string Name
  public List<Widget> Widgets
}

public class Widget {
  public int Id
  public string Name
  public WidgetLayout Layout
}

public class WidgetLayout {
  public int X
  public int Y
}
```

Using the SQLMapper method (*QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>*), I have been capable of effectively mapping the Widget to the Data class, but I am unable to locate a resource on mapping the Layout to the Widget.

Mapping via Dapper looks as such:

```
var results = (await conn.QueryAsync<Data, string, Data>(storedProc, (data, widgets) =>
List<Widget> widgetList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Widget>>(widgets); -- JSON object
data.Widgets = widgetList;
return data;
}, parameters, splitOn: "Widgets",
```

I am new to Dapper, and would like to know if it is at all possible, to map the deserialized json object so that the X and Y values are nested within the overall Widget object.

Apologies for any lack of information not provided in this question, so please let me know if additional information is required from my end.

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered changing the SQL? It's as simple as changing the column alias to `AS [layout.x]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlieface's comment, this question has been solved.

Changed the alias in the sProc and it was mapped correctly to the model in the .Net application.

From:
,[widgetLayout.X]
,[widgetLayout.Y]
...

To:
,[widgetLayout.X] as [Layout.X]
,[widgetLayout.Y] as [Layout.Y]
...

The output from the DB to the API was as I wanted, as detailed in the question.

Thank you Charlieface!